# Strange NSDate and NSDateFormatter behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get date for week of this year. this is my code and also a runtime value that is being calculated:

[image]

Why is the year not correct? Tried other formats as well, like y-w and all gave me same results. This issue does fix itself if i use YYYY-w BUT then i get wrong month/date since the year is calculated differently then. Just for information this is what i get with YYYY:

[image]

Now the date 04-29 is the correct one for week 18 in "yyyy" case (see here: http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php ) but the year is correct only when "YYYY" is used (date is wrong then).

So whats up with that?

-------- UPDATE 1 ---------

After adding solution as offered in one of answers:

[image]

-------- UPDATE 2 ----------

So my date 2000 is the same value as "no year defined" (previously it was 1970). See here: http://openradar.appspot.com/12358210

-------- UPDATE 3 ----------

System information (for those that will try replicating this).

XCode: Version 4.6.2 (4H1003)
iOS: 6.1
OSX: 10.8.3

-------- Update 4 ----------

iOS 5.1 provides different results when using this:

[image]

As if iOS 5.1 does not support "w" in NSDateFormatter.

Comment: you want to get the week number?

Comment: I have the week number. I want to get correct year, month and day by using this NSDateFormatter.

Comment: is there any restrictions on using NSCalender?

Comment: There is no restrictions on using NSCalendar but instead of working around issues like this i would like to know why am i wrong here.

Comment: what happend when you tryied like yyyy-w formatt?

Comment: yyyy-w format and results of using it is in picture #1. I tried replacing "-" with other symbols or even with text like yyyy'X'w and then providing "2013X18", but result is always the same - year is not being taken.

Comment: Locale is not set. Have tried to set it to nil, CurrentLocale, but no change in results

Comment: You can retrieve it using `[NSLocale currentLocale]` - what result do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 1**: this answer doesn't explain the results OP is seeing. See comments discussion for more info

**EDIT 2**: 
Very peculiar results on my machine. On iOS 6, week doesn't respect `first day of week` setting in `System Preferences` at all:

iOS 6 always returns:

2000-1 -> 1st Jan, 2000 (Saturday)

2001-1 -> 6th Jan, 2001 (Saturday)

Even if I do `[calendar setFirstWeekday: 3]` and `[dateFormatter setCalendar: calendar]`, doesn't affect the results at all (unlike iOS 5)! This is certainly a bug in iOS 6 NSCalendar API. I would recommend using `NSDateComponents` or calculating the date yourself. It should be easy given the info in this answer - you can assume ISO-8601 (minimum 4 days in first week and week starts with Monday), unless of course, you can ask user for their preference.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

---

Here's what's happening:

In your locale, minimum number of days in a week is `5` and week starts on a Saturday.

Assuming this is true, first week for you would be `5th Jan` (Sat) - `11th Jan 2013`. And 18th week would then be, you guessed it: `4th May 2013`.

Why? Because Apple follows [Unicode Technical Standard #35 version tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html) (on iOS 6+).

```
F.4 Week of Year

Values calculated for the Week of Year field range from 1 to 53 for the Gregorian calendar   
(they may have different ranges for other calendars). Week 1 for a year is the first week 
that contains at least the specified minimum number of days from that year. Weeks between 
week 1 of one year and week 1 of the following year are numbered sequentially from 2 to 52 
or 53 (if needed). For example, January 1, 1998 was a Thursday. If the first day of the 
week is MONDAY and the minimum days in a week is 4 (these are the values reflecting ISO 
8601 and many national standards), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997, and 
ends on January 4, 1998. However, if the first day of the week is SUNDAY, then week 1 of 
1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on January 10, 1998. The first three days of 1998 
are then part of week 53 of 1997.
```

Also, `YYYY-w` is the right format.

---

Comment: Your answer correctly explains results i get when i use week 1. Also YYYY formating is for "week year" so that explains why am i getting bad year with yyyy and also why am i getting bad week with YYYY. So question is this: How could i shift week to be correct one as provided in link (found in question) ?

Comment: Also i should note that Simulator running iOS 5.1 provides correct date with "YYYY-w", whereas iOS 6.1 provides date as shown in image #2.

Comment: But for en_US locale, the first day of the week is Sunday, not Saturday, isn't it?

Comment: @avuthless Can you print out the values of: `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] minimumDaysInFirstWeek]` and `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]` to confirm?

Comment: @MartinR That's true. Calendar doesn't depend only on locale. Although even that doesn't explain why iOS 5.1 will provide different answer from iOS 6.1. Is this a bug in 6.1?

Comment: Minimum days and first weekday both provide 1. On both iOS5.1 and iOS6.1

Comment: So *"minimum number of days in a week is 5 and week starts on a Saturday"* does not apply here. It looks more like a iOS 6 bug to me. The first week of 2013 (as I understand it) starts at December 30, 2012, and that is also the (correct) result of parsing "2013-1" with "YYYY-w" on iOS 5. iOS 6 returns "January 5, 2013" for these parameters which does not make any sense at all.

Comment: Yep, my answer is not right. @avuthless Please unmark it as answer so others can chime in. But I will do some more research before writing this off as a bug in iOS 6.1. Will update.

Comment: I believe that several iOS 6 bugs have been noted in the "stranger" date conversion functions.  This problem should be filed as a bug.

Comment: Marked this answer as correct. Reworked everything on NSCalendar, but then found that NSQuarterCalendarUnit has bug and does not work too. Two Apple bugs on one day.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using NSCalender then you'l get all the compontens like this,

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];
    NSInteger year = [components1 year];
    NSInteger week=[components1 weekOfYear];
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but as i mentioned in comments i am not seeking for another way to do this. I am seeking an answer to why is NSDateFormatter ignoring year input for format "yyyy-w"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-18";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-ww"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date: %@",date);
```

Comment: Updated question with results from your solution.